# how to remove a slide in jquery cycle?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using this plugin: [jquery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

I have several slideshows running at the same time, each starts with a logo of a client and the rest of the images are picutres of their work.

I would like to remove the logo slide once I'm starting to view the rest of the slides so when the slideshows loops I will no longer see the logo slide and continue with the first one of the picture set

How can I achieve that?

My current code:

```
var $li = $("#somediv ul li");

$li.each(function(i)
{
    var random_ms = randomFromInterval(5, 10) * 1000;

    $(this).cycle({
        fx: "fade, scrollUp, scrollDown, scrollLeft, scrollRight",
        timeout: random_ms,
        delay: -3500
    }); 
});
```

this [solution](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-jquery-cycle-remove-slide) didn't worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, finally this is what I did: inside go() -line 623 in version 2.9999.5- the first instruction must be

```
if(opts.nextSlide == 0)
{
    opts.nextSlide++;
}
```

before this line:

```
var p = opts.$cont[0], curr = els[opts.currSlide], next = els[opts.nextSlide];
```